# Does the Docker RPM require additional dependencies?

Tags: linux, docker, dependencies, rpm

I couldn't find an answer online, help would be appreciated.

I have downloaded the Docker RPM for CentOS 7 from their site (http://docs.docker.com/v1.7/docker/installation/centos).

After installing the RPM, does Docker require any additional dependencies in order to run? Or is the standalone RPM enough?

I'm asking because it takes time to bring external files into my company's network. So I'd like to know in advance all of the dependencies (RPMs or other files) I need to bring into the network, along with the Docker RPM, so I can do it all at once.

Comment: Have you tried asking the package itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a lot of dependencies.

You can use a tool call *repotrack* to download the Docker Engine RPM and all of it's dependencies.

`repotrack docker-engine`

There's a similar tool out there called *yumdownloader*, it won't work for your use case because it only downloads the rpms needed for the specific Centos/RHEL server that you run the command on. Repotrack downloads all, not taking into account what is already installed on the system.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm running Windows at home, and I have to download the Docker RPM and all dependencies at home, and bring them into the company's private network. Will repotrack work on my Windows machine?

Comment: You'd have to setup a CentOS 7 VM on your Windows machine and do it through that.  (Try to have the exact same OS version, if it's CentOS 7.2 at work, have a CentOS 7.2 VM)

Comment: I see. After doing that, I want to be able to take all the downloaded RPMs, and bring them to my company for installation on the server there. Will this be possibe using repotrack?

Comment: By the way, does `repotrack docker-engine` download recursively (or does it stop at the first level of dependencies)? Also, where does it put the RPM files for me to take? Thanks

Comment: It will download all necessary rpms into the current working directory.  Here's a tip - 1.use `createrepo` to generate the metadata to make it a yum repo 2. tar up the entire directory 3. copy the archive to your target host, decompress 4. create local yum repo pointing to that directory 5. yum install docker-engine